# Show $E[h(X)] = \int_0^{\infty} h'(t)P[X>t]dt$ and the first two moments

Tags: expectation, stochastic-integrals, moment-generating-functions

Let $X\geq 0$ be a real random variable and $h:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a monotonously growing, continuously differentiable function with $h(0)=0$.

Show:

$E[h(X)] = \int_0^{\infty} h'(t)P[X>t]dt$

With the given hint I got

$E[h(X)] = \int_0^{\infty} \int_{0}^x h'(t)dt dF(x)$

with Fubinis theorem I can change the order of integration to

$\int_0^{\infty} \left( \int_{t}^{\infty} dF(x)\right)h'(t)dt$
which gives me

$\int_0^{\infty} P[X>t]h'(t)dt$

How would I go about finding the first two moments in integral form like above?

I got this far:
first moment

$E[X] = \int_0^{\infty} x F(x) dx = \int_0^{\infty}\int_0^{x}dx F(x) dt = \int_0^{\infty}\int_t^{\infty} F(x) dx dt = \int_0^{\infty}P[X>t]dt$

second moment

$E[X^2] = \int_0^{\infty} x^2 F(x) dx = \int_0^{\infty}\int_0^{x}2x F(x) dx dt = 2\int_0^{\infty}\int_t^{\infty} x F(x) dx dt$

But now what? $\int_t^{\infty}x dx$ doesn't converge.

Comment: Hint: Try to prove it using a modification of the integration by parts.

Comment: can you please put this question off hold? I think I complied to the guidelines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only explicit question seems to ask to explain where the following computation is faulty:

> $E[X^2] = \int_0^{\infty} x^2 F(x) dx = \int_0^{\infty}\int_0^{x}2x F(x) dx dt = 2\int_0^{\infty}\int_t^{\infty} x F(x) dx dt$

Already the first equal sign is wrong. If $X$ has a **density** $f$ then
$$
E(X^2)=\int_0^\infty x^2f(x)\mathrm dx,
$$
but for every random variable $X$, if $F$ is the CDF of $X$ then $F(x)\to1$ when $x\to\infty$ hence
$$
\int_0^\infty x^2F(x)\mathrm dx=+\infty.
$$
Another mistake lurks in the computation of the first moment, since you write:

> $E[X] = \int_0^{\infty} x F(x) dx = \int_0^{\infty}\int_0^{x}dx F(x) dt = \int_0^{\infty}\int_t^{\infty} F(x) dx dt = \int_0^{\infty}P[X>t]dt$

Here again, if $F$ is the CDF of $X$ the first equal sign is wrong, for the same reasons. And the last equal sign is wrong as well, since, for every $t$,
$$
\int_t^{\infty} F(x) \mathrm dx
$$
is equal to $+\infty$, not to $P(X\gt t)$.

What you are asked to do is simply to plug in $h(x)=x$ and $h(x)=x^2$ in the formula you first proved, namely,
$$
E(h(X)) = \int_0^{\infty} h'(t)P(X>t)\mathrm dt,
$$
leading to
$$
E(X) = \int_0^{\infty}P(X>t)\mathrm dt,
\qquad
E(X^2) = \int_0^{\infty} 2tP(X>t)\mathrm dt.
$$

Comment: oh god. how did I not see that? thank you for clearing this up for me.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** If $F$ is the CDF of $X$, then 
$$
E[h(X)] = \int_0^{\infty} h(x) \, dF(x) = \int_0^{\infty} \int_{0}^x h'(t) \, dt \, dF(x).
$$
Now interchange the order of integration.

Comment: thanks. With Fubini I was able to solve this part of the problem.